# jquery ui accordion broken when clicking back button after PJAX load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, pjax

I am using PJAX (jquery-pjax) and pjax_rails to navigate Rails application.

On page 1, I have a jquery ui accordion.

When I click some pjax-enabled link, page 2 content is pjax-loaded correctly

When I click the back button, page 1 content is pjax-loaded but the accordion then seems broken i.e. when I click to open another tab, the open one remains open, and calling .accordion('option','active') in the activate and beforeActivate event handlers returns -1.

Further clicks on closed tabs headers will open them, but the originally open tab still remains open.

Clicking the originally open tab's header, then clicking another one will finally make the accordion render as expected, but .accordion('option','active') still returns -1.

I tried using Firebug to interact with the accordion in the 'broken' state, and it is irresponsive to .accordion('destroy').

Using .accordion('option','active', 2) fires the associated events but the UI isn't updated. Requesting .accordion('option','active') then however correctly returns 2.

Has anyone experienced something similar? Any idea on how to solve this, i.e. have a working accordion after pressing the back button following a pjax state update?

Thanks!

pjax_rails : https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails
jquery ui accordion : http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ (I'm using the 1.9.0m8 version)

Answer (score 0):

Pjax clones the HTML state of the current page before navigating and then caches it. When you click back it pulls that clone out of the cache again, but no javascript gets re-initialized at that point.

What I'd suggest as a general rule is destroying any jquery-ui items during `$(document).on('pjax:start')` and re-initializing them on `$(document).on('pjax:end')`.